# How to refresh fragment from base fragment

Tags: android

Sorry for bad English.

I have BaseFragment. it contains Search View and View Pager and View pager has three fragement like Fragment A,B,C

Fragment B has Listview.
so whenever i am doing search i got search response in Base fragment now what i want to do is push these response to fragment B listview inside viewpager. when every time search action perform and need to refresh listview.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20553879/refresh-fragment-views-based-on-button-click

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0):

You can get an instance of the fragment you want by calling Fragment manager like this:

```
 CustomFragment fragment = (CustomFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_a);
```

and then you can call any methods of the fragment like this:

```
fragment.update(data);
```

But make sure you check the fragment is not null before calling its methods.